# Problematic Menshutkin reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

I'm quite new to organic chemistry and want to try menshutkin reaction. Like the reaction in an attachment.

I use that recipe:

I do everything in a 60ml beaker. I dissolve 18 mmol of pyridine in 35 ml of acetone. I add 115 mmol of 1,6-dibromohexane and stir for 30 minutes. Then I add 76.6 mmol KOH (in the form of crushed pre-flakes). Stir for the next 24 hours.

Then I put the whole thing into a solution of 50 ml of dichloromethane and 100 ml of water. I mix for 1 hour, then pour into a funnel (I have a small 25ml one, so I do it several times).

I evaporate the whole thing using a 60-80 degree water bath until all the dichloromethane evaporates. Then, after cooling down, I wash it a few times with pentane (it cleans the material from the residual dibromohexane, unfortunately I don't have a vacuum pump).

Unfortunately, I only got 5% yield and the product still look little reddish, what am I doing wrong? Could you help me on what to do better?

I can buy equipment but not so sure what to buy

[image]

Comment: Dichloromethane? That's a bad idea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menshutkin_reaction

Comment: I mean when the reaction end of course, to transfer product to organic phase, It's not my imagination it's one of the procedure from Reaxys base. What do you think will be better that boils low temperature?

Comment: Hmm, at this point it's probably indeed OK. Maybe adding pyridine drop-wise would help?

Comment: Last time I add 1,6-dibromohexane drop-wise, but can try with the amine drop-wise. The water-dichloromethane washing and pentane washing is ok? I thought maybe the reaction time is to long and another pirydine is brought to second bromine atom?

Comment: Yeah, you need to do what you can to avoid disubstitution - adding pyridine slowly during reaction would be good idea.

Comment: What will be the best solvent to make a reaction in? I had also toluene, pentane, DMF. After the reaction how much of DCM use? Can I use like 1g-15ml or need to use more? Will it be better to buy bigger separatory funnel? Could occuring the reaction in 25-30 C degrees be good?

Comment: Maybe wait if someone with experience in this reaction comes around.